# GCP dataflow SQL export using service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a service account access to a BQ view and I want to query it and export the data to GCS or a BQ dataset in another project.

Dataflow (+create job from SQL) looks perfect for the use case but I can't work out how to set it up so the service account is used for the query.  It appears Dataflow accepts using a service account but how is this done?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you want to create dataflow sql? A simple query is enough for the 2 use cases. Why this choice?

Comment: what simple query can i do to select * from the view and export into json?  feels the only option is write a script to do this?  that is why i was looking at dataflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export data to another BigQuery table, you can simply use an `INSERT INTO <table> SELECT * FROM ...` (also known as INSERT-SELECT). If you need to export this regularly, you can use [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries)

if you want to export to Google Cloud Storage, you have 2 solutions

- Export a full table, and use [BigQuery export API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#api) (you can call this API with Cloud Scheduler if you want to regularly export them)
- Use [export query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement) statement.